# Sine / cosine of sum ot angles in two definitions

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Consider a right triangle with legs $a$ and $b$, and hypotenuse $c$. Angle $\alpha$ is in-between $a$ and $c$. We can now define trigonometric functions like sine or cosine. Over the Internet there are various derivations of sine / cones formulas for sum of angles (for example $\sin (\alpha + \beta)$).

Consider now we move to analytical geometry. Consider a point $(x,y)$ which will form an angle $\alpha$ with $X$ axis (I know this is not very precise, but I believe all know what I mean without making drawings - I hope). We can now define (for example) sine as

$$
\sin\alpha = \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}
$$

A different angle $\beta$ will be related to point $(x',y')$. As long as we are in the 1st quadrant (angles from 0 do 90 deg.) both definitions coincide, thus the geometric derivation of the $\sin (\alpha + \beta)$ formula is still valid. However, what happens if we exceed 90 deg. and any of angles $\alpha$, $\beta$ or $\alpha+\beta$ goes beyond acute angle? Obviously the formula still works, but how to prove it in this rather general case?

EDIT no. 1

This is basically a question about a proof of these sum of angles formulas for all angles. In some of my very old books I have found a proof using reduction formulas, and simply checking all possible cases (for example $\phi = 90^{\circ} + \alpha$, $\delta = 90^{\circ} + \beta$, $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\alpha+\beta < 90^{\circ}$, prove that $\sin(\phi+\delta)=\sin(\alpha+\beta)$, etc.). But this is very tedious proof and I believe it must exist a better one, more general, which uses only geometrical considerations.

EDIT no. 2

After some thinking I came up with this. Consider any angle $\gamma$. It can **always** be expressed as $\alpha + n \frac{\pi}{2}$, where $n$ any integer (positive or negative), and $0 < \alpha < \frac{\pi}{2}$. The same is for any angle $\delta = \beta + m \frac{\pi}{2}$. Basically the task is to prove that $\sin(\gamma + \delta) = \sin(\alpha + \beta + (n+m)\frac{\pi}{2})$ equals $\sin(\alpha + \beta)$, but now I'm not sure where the condition of $\alpha + \beta < \frac{\pi}{2}$ comes into.

Comment: $e^{ia}=cos(a)+isin(a)$.  Manipulate algebra with $a=\alpha$, $a=\beta$, and $a=\alpha+\beta$.using $e^{i\alpha}\times e^{i\beta}=e^{i(\alpha+\beta)}$

Comment: @herbsteinberg I believe the OP wants a geometrical proof. Well, in that case I don’t think you can do better than considering cases. However, I wouldn’t worry too much about them.

Comment: Did you try to use the unit circles and relations between area related to the various values?

Comment: Yes, I was hoping for a geometrical proof, without use of advanced analysis. I made some edits to my post with some ideas I came up with.

Comment: Scroll down to 'trig functions of compound angles' [here](http://amsi.org.au/ESA_Senior_Years/SeniorTopic2/2d/2d_2content_4.html). Is this the kind of thing you are looking for?